# No sound on any other device if HDMI is plugged in

Tags: sound, hdmi, headphones, speakers

On Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, when the monitor's HDMI cable is plugged in, sound always gets routed to the monitor. It doesn't matter what I choose in the settings, it is ignored. I have tried switching the output device in the Audio Settings. Tweaking the monitor's audio setting has no effect either.

The only way I can plug in external speakers is via the port on the monitor, not the laptop.

Any clues on how to fix it will be much appreciated.